# Plausible reason why the astronauts wouldn’t get involved in the aliens war?

Tags: warfare, interspecies-relations, gods

So, two astronauts, Gregory and Jessica, just got marooned on an alien planet. They went down into a Canyon, were they discovered some tiny, and sized beings, who had developed into a Bronze Age. They have cities, ships, and much more advancements.

Gregory and Jessica, who are both average humans, are mistaken for Gods by the tiny beings, for their great size, strength and long lives, as the beings live only a few hours. They argue about who is the true, ultimate god, and the civilization breaks into two. The Jessicans, and the Gregorians.

Greg, who has always been sort of a klutz, accidentally steps on, and destroys, the great Jessican cities of Tan Anna, Lon Janai, and Cara-Nova. In retaliation, the Jessicans attack the coastal city of Han-Lin, setting it ablaze.

Their is soon to be an incredible war between them, a naval war on the “Great Sea”. The Great Sea, is in reality, a medium sized lake that both Greg and Jessica could wade in, as its only about 3 meters at its deepest point.

Both Greg and Jessica know that this naval battle is about to go down, so my question is, why might they not help their worshippers by just getting into the water and destroying all their ships?

Comment: Hello, *Greg*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  Unfortunately, this question seems to be about the actions of characters in a story, rather than about building a world.  Perhaps you could edit to address this concern.  Please visit our [help] and take the [tour].  Have a nice day!

Comment: It sounds like Jessica has an attachment to her tiny beings since she retaliated against Gregs mistake and destroys a city. This suggests that Jessica would take part in the naval battle where Greg might just sit out because he doesn't appear to have the same attachment. Maybe they just don't want to get wet? If you have a klutz astronaut that could be enough  of a reason

Comment: Greg,  You've asked us to write a criticl plot point about your story rather than help develop the rules of your world in a consistent manner.  To avoid having your question closed as too story-based, please [read this post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/when-should-i-close-a-question-as-too-story-based), then edit and adjust yours accordingly.

Comment: @Shadowzee It was the *Jessicans* who retaliated not Jessica herself.

Comment: Sorry to point out the obvious. Greg and Jessica are marooned on an alien planet. Why should they want to get involved in a local conflict? They can just walk away and concentrate on getting off the planet.

Comment: @a4android ah right, completely missed that small extension of Jessica.

Comment: @Shadowzee It's so easy to do.We all get caught by it.

Comment: @a4android, actually, I'm wonderin' how ant-sized intelligent creatures with a lifespan of only hours has the necessary cogent time per-individual to develop the technology to build a navy.

Comment: @JBH Now that's a good question. probably a combination of faster brain processing speeds, highly developed social communication & good record-keeping. After all, in humans science, engineering & culture are products of our social intelligence. The critters would have to have very good social intelligence.

Comment: @a4android I could imagine some kind of swarm intelligence, with which every new born being receives the older generation's knowledge and/or memories right away

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher The tricky part is working out a mechanism for doing that. I can imagine cannibalism as one way of doing this. to directly ingest memory & knowledge from the previous generation. My original idea was that the memory & knowledge is held globally by the species' social intelligence. Individuals aren't smart, but they are collectively intelligent.

Comment: @a4android Well, transmitting information in the brain happens with electrical impulses. This might be one way, they "connect" to each other and transmit these electrical impulses via contact or through the air, via light/sound/electromagnetic wave emitting organs or pheromones, spores or any other means of transporting information. They might form colonies with a queen acting as a central information point, which leads to a more evenly distributed collective knowledge or form a snowball-like system and receive the information of surrounding individuals passing it on to the next ones.

Comment: @a4android However, I do like the idea of literally eating the information of the old or deceased ones. It's intriguingly morbid :) The difficulty is that you only receive the information of the eaten individual, how do you get all the memories, experience and knowledge of the others? Everyone would have to eat everyone. Create a huge banquet of mashed brain soup out of everyone who died yesterday for everyone else to enjoy?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is that they have moral objections to killing the beings.  Since they are so small, it will be difficult to stop their fighting without injuring or killing them by accident.  Greg already did kill some of their people.  Unless they can figure out a clever way of stopping the fighting without harming anyone, they may not feel able to interfere.

They may also worry their interference could be interpreted in a way that causes more bloodshed.  it is clear that there are some tensions among the society that led to them so easily going to war, so they may use any excuse to further the war.  After all, most religions have a God, and we've no scientific evidence one exists or has acted upon the world, but societies have gone to war in God's name for millenia.

Also consider the size of the people and the lake.  Merely stepping foot or moving around in the water could cause ripples, which are minuscule to a human, but are tidal waves to a being of tiny size.

There's also the "Star Trek" answer of having some kind of directive that prevents them from interacting or interfering with alien lifeforms.

From a storytelling perspective, however, I feel that it is far more interesting to explore all the ways them trying to intervene fails miserably than have them not intervene.

Comment: Marshall Yes!!!

Comment: First paragraph: They step into the water and kiss in front of the fleets for everyone to see and stop the massacre.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher that assumes that the aliens have the same modes of affection we do.  What if a kiss among them is a chief insult?  Or an aggressive act?  Consider eye contact.  Most western cultures believe maintaining eye contact shows interest in the conversation and should be done, especially to superiors.  In Asian cultures, though, not making eye contact is a sign of respect.  There are many examples just among humans, so imagine how many there'd be with a completely different alien species.

Comment: Sure, the outcome of the idea itself might not be what the astronauts had in mind, that's up to the storyteller. You may also replace the kiss with anything else the creatures are able to understand depending on whether the astronauts are living on the planet long enough to find out.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher agreed, though I would, as a reader, find it pretty implausible for an alien race to have similar nonverbals to us, though.

Comment: If they're a civilized species they might easily be able to differentiate between various kinds of interaction. It's not hard to read a confrontation between two dogs being playful, affectionate or aggressive, even though you're not a dog (yes, sometimes it can be tricky). Other animals are much more proficient in doing so as they rely more on their instincts and less on their mind. It would make total sense to me if the astronauts showed some true affection for one another, that at least one of the tiny creatures read the situation correctly and pointed it out to others.